# Do I still need to use an Ordered Dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, ordereddictionary, ordereddict

So, I was wondering if I still needed to use an Ordered Dictionary for this.

```py
import requests
import time
import collections
import threading
 
 
class LiveChecker:
    """Editable YT streamer checker. Meant to be used with a discord bot. Edit the module directly to change which streamers to track."""
    def __init__(self):
 
        self.headers = {'Accept-Encoding' : 'identity'}
 
        self.initial = {  'Gura':'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCoSrY_IQQVpmIRZ9Xf-y93g',    #name as key, link as value
                          'Calli':'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCL_qhgtOy0dy1Agp8vkySQg',  
                          'Kiara':'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCHsx4Hqa-1ORjQTh9TYDhww',   
                          'Ina':'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCMwGHR0BTZuLsmjY_NT5Pwg',
                          'Ame':'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCyl1z3jo3XHR1riLFKG5UAg',
                          'Noel':'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCdyqAaZDKHXg4Ahi7VENThQ',
                          'Pekora':'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1DCedRgGHBdm81E1llLhOQ',
                          'Suisei':'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC5CwaMl1eIgY8h02uZw7u8A',
                          'Okayu':'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCvaTdHTWBGv3MKj3KVqJVCw',
                          'Korone':'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UChAnqc_AY5_I3Px5dig3X1Q',
                          'Flare':'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCvInZx9h3jC2JzsIzoOebWg',
                          'Ollie':'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYz_5n-uDuChHtLo7My1HnQ',
                          'Moona':'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCP0BspO_AMEe3aQqqpo89Dg',
                          'Rushia':'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCl_gCybOJRIgOXw6Qb4qJzQ',
                          'Coco':'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCS9uQI-jC3DE0L4IpXyvr6w',
                          'Aqua':'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1opHUrw8rvnsadT-iGp7Cg',
                          'Subaru':'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCvzGlP9oQwU--Y0r9id_jnA'}
 
        self.OD = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(self.initial.items())) # used to keep the dict consistent (and sorted through
                                                                        # alphabetical order)
        
 
    def checker(self, name, link):
        live = requests.get(link, headers = self.headers)
        if '{"accessibilityData":{"label":"LIVE"}}},"style":"LIVE","icon":{"iconType":"LIVE"}' in live.text:
            states = "**LIVE**"
        else:
            states = "*Offline*"
        self.toAnswer += [f"{name}: {states}"]
 
        
    def gettp(self):
        self.toAnswer = []
        threads = []
        for i in self.OD.keys():
            process = threading.Thread(target = self.checker, args = [i, self.OD[i]])
            process.start()
            threads.append(process)
 
        for process in threads:
            process.join()
        print(f"STREAMER STATES: Updated ({time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.localtime())})")
 
 
    def getRes(self):
        return ('\n'.join(sorted(self.toAnswer)))
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__': # Debugging
    from os import system
    system("title yts Debug")
    wl = LiveChecker()
    while True:
        wl.gettp()
        print(wl.getRes())
        time.sleep(3)
# forgive my weeb!
```

I read somewhere that dictionaries weren't ordered, so I thought making it ordered would make it, at the very least, consistent. However, I read a more recent thing that said that dictionaries were now inherently ordered by entry, just like what an ordereddict is.

So I was wondering, in the example above, if it was still necessary to keep using an Ordered Dict.

Comment: Did you test it also with normal dicts?

Comment: It depends on what your Python version is. As of 3.7, standard `dict` types are ordered.

Comment: yes... thank you for the answers. It does work with standard dicts. In hindsight, I should've tested it before. Thank you again!